# Leaflet sidebar-v2 issue with overlapping

Tags: dictionary, leaflet, sidebar, overlap

Maybe someone know where is the problem, why my sidebar overlap header and footer.

HTML

```
<div id="sidebar" class="sidebar collapsed">
  //sidebar content
</div>

<div id="map" class="sidebar-map"></div>
```

CSS

```
#map {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  height:100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Old version of sidebar working properly.

Comment: http://oi58.tinypic.com/14d0f3o.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although it's hard to say without a proper testcase on JSfiddle or Plunker but: how about setting `margin-top` and `margin-bottom` on `#sidebar` your sidebar element?

CSS:

```
#sidebar {
    margin-top: ?px;
    margin-bottom: ?px;
}
```

Comment: The footer does not have a fixed height, it depends on screen resolution. In this case sidebar is not equal to the map height. I need to set the sidebar to dimensions of the map. that happens if I put sidebar div into the map div, but then .leaflet-left (zoom control,...) is pushed on right side 400-500px.

Comment: Maybe you can create a testcase, preferrably on Plunker? Here's a boilerplate with sidebar v2 included: http://plnkr.co/edit/5GnUQK

Comment: I fixed bottom of the page on the bottom of screen (html, body {height: calc(100% - 26px);}), and then used margin-top and margin-down. It worked out for me.

Comment: @iH8 I would love to use yur template as a basis. When I download it and run, the line includes: (L.Evented.prototype || L.Mixin.Events),` gives leaflet-sidebar.js:13 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined
    at leaflet-sidebar.js:13
(anonymous) @ leaflet-sidebar.js:13
script.js:11 Uncaught TypeError: L.control.sidebar is not a function
    at script.js:11 Any idea what I did wrong?  BTW, is there any documentation for Leaflet Sidebar V2?